# Firefox scrolls choppy with background-position:fixed;

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, position, background-image

I´m having a DIV with

```
 #myDiv{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        overflow:hidden;
        background-image:url('../images/test.png');
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-attachment:fixed;
        background-position:100% 0;
 }
```

So this will work but I´m having trouble with scrolling in Firefox. If I´m scrolling this with my mousewheel and a image more than 1MB firefox is choppy and not smooth. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Cannot you just reduce size of image?!

Comment: No sorry, it´s a full background-image and must have min 1900px width